# Unable to cast object Type Error

Tags: c#, oop

Unable to cast object Type Error

Code

```
class Person
    {
        public int Addition(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
    class Developer : Person
    {
        public void Addition(int a, int b)
        {
            int sum = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}{1}" + sum);
        }
    }
    class CHashDeveloper : Developer
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Developer objDeveloper =(Developer) new Person(); // Error Occurred here
        }
```

what I need to do so that I can resolve such error.
        }

Comment: It's pronounced "C _Sharp_".

Comment: Why are ppl downvoting :( It could be a poor question, but it isn't wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Person` is not a `Developer`.
You can only cast an object to a type that the object actually *is*.

If you want to create a `Developer`, you need to write that: `new Developer()`.